# modify public string with default value in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an string like "0000000"
and declared it in a class

```
public class Days_string
{
    private string days= "0000000";  
    public string Days    
    {
        get
        {
           return days;
        }
        set
        {
            days = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and I tried to change the string by clicking on 7 buttons
like this:

```
Days_string daystr = new Days_string();
var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(daystr.Days);
aStringBuilder.Remove(5, 1);
aStringBuilder.Insert(5, "1");
daystr.Days = aStringBuilder.ToString();
```

the output is 0000010

but it changed to 0000000 when I call it again

whats should i do?

Comment: Well you're creating a new instance of `Days_string` each time... don't do that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Jon, don't you ever sleep?

Comment: You can use static property to keep value for all instance of the Days_string.

Comment: Not directly related with your problem, but wouldn't that be easier if you used a single byte to store this information? You could simply turn the corresponding bit on/off (strings are immutable).

Comment: Stop creating new `daystr` instances, that's where your problem is...

Comment: thanks ,yes create one instance solved the problem// maybe use of static property could do same( i didnt try that) thank you all // @Cetin Basoz i need to replase "1" with "2" somewhere else  but Honestly i didnt think about that.

Comment: Then for the sake of simplicity I would keep it as an array (byte[], char[], string[] ...). It is easier then doing a remove and insert or checking with substring. ie: var days = new byte[7];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use static variable and static properties instead.and access the properties using className.properties name

```
public class Days_string
{
    private static string days = "0000000";
    public static string Days
    {
        get
        {
            return days;
        }
        set
        {
            days = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the code is strange, but to solve your problem, you have at least two options:

1. Use an static variable :

   private static string days = "0000000";
2. Or, create a global Days_string instance inside your form. By now, you are creating a new Days_string instance behind each button!